# Extjs- Error during sencha app build

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I'm trying to compact my Ext.js project using `sencha app build` and this error occurred:

```html
[ERR] loading page .../sass/example/theme.html
Failed to load page
 
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: phantomjs process exited with code 100
[ERR]   at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodIn
[ERR] voker.java:175)
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 1 minute 22 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
...\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:334: The following error occurred while executing this line:
```

My sencha cmd version is v6.2.1.29.
My EXT JS version is 6.2.0.981.
I already have the file theme.html.

Comment: is path correct for theme.html

Comment: I think so. 
theme.html is located on 'sass/example'

Comment: Ya, Placement is correct. This error may be you getting because of some url is missing. Please check path of Ext. Where you placed you libraries and what path you fetching.

Comment: I'm on 'projectname/ext' which path should libraries be?